# Spark dataset.map from stage0 repeats in other stages

Tags: loops, apache-spark, dataset, stage

This is related to my other post : [Spark Java Map processing entire data set in all executors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75035103/spark-java-map-processing-entire-data-set-in-all-executors)
.
I have a simple use case:

1. Read data from DB in 4 partitions

   ```
    properties.setProperty("partitionColumn", "num_rows");
    properties.setProperty("lowerBound", "0");
    properties.setProperty("upperBound", getTotalRowCount(ID));
    properties.setProperty("numPartitions", "4");
    properties.setProperty("Driver", driver);
    properties.setProperty("user", user);
    properties.setProperty("password", password);
    Dataset<Row> records = SparkSession.getActiveSession().get().read().jdbc(jdbcUrl, table, properties);
   ```
2. process the recordset in a loop to convert/filter/format etc.,

   ```
    Dataset<String> stringRecordSet = dbRecordsSet.map((MapFunction<Row, String> )xmlRow -> {
            return TransformationService.extractXMLBlobToString(xmlRow);
        }, Encoders.STRING());   Dataset < Row > jsonDataSet = sparkSession.read().json(stringifiedDataSet);
   ```
3. simply save this:

   jsonDataSet.write().format("csv").save(filepath);

Issue: My dataset has 40 rows.  Steps 2 processes each partition in parallel in a loop as expected. But in step3 when I save the recordset in the file system, that stage3 reexecutes stage2 to process the partitions all over again. the function inside .map (TransformationService.extractXMLBlobToString) is called again for all 40 records. In production I have dataset in millions. stage0 has the loop to process my data in the right format, stage1 is save, but this stage reprocesses the loop, So I see a dataset of 10 million records is processed twice unncessarily. Why is this happening? If I do a cache between step 2 and 3, it increases the time by two fold. Not helping at all. my processing time went from 5 mins to 10 mins. Can someone please help me understand why SAVE calls the loop again?

Comment: How have you verified that your `step 2` is being executed twice? Normally, your `step 2` is a transformation. This means that this is *lazily* evaluated. It should only be executed when you call an action on its result. `df.write().format("csv").save(filepath);` is an action, so it makes sense that your calculations are taking place in `step 3`.

Comment: Hi, I added logging statements inside the loop in step2, I am converting blob to string and printing the part of string, so I know for sure it executes twice. Also I do have an action right after map to convert string to json. that is the action that triggered the transofmration in step2. I will update the above code now to add this action, so it will be clear

Comment: So if there are two actions in the code, does the transformation repeat for all over again in every stage? This seems utterly nonperformant. My loop inside the transformation is extremely non-performant. Because this is a jdbc dataset with unknown data size (blob) I cant even calculate how many partitions I need. I am only allocating 10 partitions to keep jdbc connections to minimum. WIth millions of records if the expensive transformation repeats with every action this data extract code will execute for hours or even days if the dataset if huge. In my actual code I have 4 different actions

Comment: Is it true that all previously performed transformations done with Stage0 will repeat in stage1? I hope this is not true, and if so how do I overcome this? I put a cache in between stages, it shot up execution the time by 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Your `map` transformation is executed twice because you are calling 2 actions on its result without caching in between. You two actions are:

- `Dataset < Row > jsonDataSet = sparkSession.read().json(stringifiedDataSet);`

  - this is an action because you did not supply any schema to your `DataFrameReader` object, so it has to infer a schema for your dataframe, necessitating an immediate action
- `jsonDataSet.write().format("csv").save(filepath);`

You could try:

- caching `stringRecordSet`. This is the default solution for these kinds of problems
- in this case, you might turn the `sparkSession.read().json(stringifiedDataSet);` action into a lazy transformation by supplying it with a schema, like so: `sparkSession.read().schema(schema).json(stringifiedDataSet);`

Comment: ah!!! that may be the solution to my problem. will try schema today and will post the result here. thank  you

Comment: that fixed the issue. thank you :) Now there is a foreachPartition that is now causing another loop. I fetch DB, loop to parse blob into json, and then have a foreachPartition loop that calculates the size of records in each partition, then repartition if a partition size exceeds 1GB and save to disk, or just save without repartition. So the loop executes once for 'foreachpartition' and once for 'save' (without reparition). How can I avoid this double loop? DOing it on MapPartition is returning 0 in the accumulator. Appreciate your help. thank you